# Spectrum of positive linear operators defined for every $L^p$ space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory, reflexive-space

Consider the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]), \lambda(\mathrm{d} x)  )$, where $\mathcal B([0,1])$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measgure on $[0,1]$.

Let $P,T:L^1([0,1]) \to L^1([0,1])$ operators satisfying the following properties:

- For every $p\in [1,\infty],$
  $$ \left.P\right|_{L^p[0,1]},\left.T\right|_{L^p[0,1]}:  L^p [0,1] \to L^p[0,1],$$
  is well defined and a bounded linear operator.
- For every $p \in [1,\infty]$
  $$\left(\left. T\right|_{L^p([0,1])}\right)^* = \left.P\right|_{L^{p^*}([0,1])},$$
  where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^*} = 1 \ \text{and }{}^*\ \text{denotes the adjoint operator}. $
- If $0 \leq f \in L^p$ then $0\leq T f $ and $0\leq Pf.$ I think this hypothesis is not relevant.

For every $p\in [1,\infty]$ let us define
$$\sigma (T,p ) :=  \sigma (\left. T\right|_{L^p}) \ \text{and } \sigma (P,p ) :=  \sigma (\left. P\right|_{L^p}),$$
where $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of the operator $T$.

> **Question:** Is it possible to conclude that $\sigma(T,1) = \sigma(T, p)$ or $\sigma(T,\infty) = \sigma(T,p)$, for all $p\in (1,\infty).$?

Comment: I can give an example but on a discrete $\ell^p$ spaces. Are you interested ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes! I would be really interested on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed sequence of positive numbers $\omega=\{\omega_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$  consider the weighted spaces $\ell^p(\omega_n)$ defined by
$$\ell^p(\omega)=\left \{x=\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty \,:\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|^p\omega_n <\infty \right \}$$ with norm $$\|x\|_p=\left (\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|^p\omega_n \right)^{1\over p}.$$
The space $\ell^p(\omega)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the standard space $\ell^p$ by the mapping
$$\ell^p(\omega) \ni \{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty\longmapsto  \{x_n\,\omega_n^{1/p}\}_{n=0}^\infty \in \ell^p$$
Let $\omega_n=2^{n}.$ Consider the shift operator $T:\ell^p(\omega)\to \ell^p(\omega),$ acting by $(Tx)_n=x_{n+1}.$ The operator $T$ preserves positivity of the sequences. The operator $T$ is bounded:
$$\|Tx\|_p^p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_{n+1}|^p2^n={1\over 2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_{n+1}|^p2^{n+1}\le {1\over 2}\|x\|_p^p$$ hence
$\|T\|_{p\to p}\le 2^{-1/p}.$ For $x=\delta_1$ we get $\|T\delta_1\|_p=\|\delta_0\|_p=2^{-1/p}\|\delta_1\|_p.$ Therefore $$\hspace{5cm}\|T\|_{p\to p}=2^{-1/p}\hspace{5cm} (1)$$
The adjoint operator $T^*$ acts by the formula $$(T^*x)(n)={\omega_{n-1}\over 
\omega_n}x_{n-1}={1\over 2} x_{n-1},$$ with convention $x_{-1}=\omega_{-1}=0.$

Let $\sigma(T,p)$ denote the spectrum of $T:\ell^p(\omega)\to \ell^p(\omega).$ We will show that
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad \sigma(T,p)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, |z|\le 2^{-1/p}\}\qquad \ \ \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad (2)$$
The  inclusion "$\subset $" follows from $(1).$
Let $|z|<2^{-1/p}.$ Then the sequence $v_z=\{z^n\}_{n=0}^\infty $ belongs to $ \ell^p(\omega)$ and $Tv_z=z\,v_z.$ Therefore the number $z$ is an eigevalue of $T:\ell^p(\omega)\to \ell^p(\omega).$ Hence $z\in \sigma(T,p),$ i.e.
$$\{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, |z|< 2^{-1/p}\}\subset \sigma(T,p)$$
This concludes the proof of $(2).$

Comment: Awesome example! However, there is one thing that I am a bit confused about. I believe that we could repeat the same arguments done in "comments" to your example. Then we would have that $\sigma(T, p) = \sigma (T, q)$ for every $p,q \in (1,\infty)$. However, this is not the case here... I wonder what mistake I made.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. I was assuming that $\sigma_p (T) \subset_p (T^*),$ where $\sigma_p$ is the point spectrum. And this is completely false. I removed the section "comments" to not confuse future readers.